# SQLBindParameter with variable length strings

Tags: db2, db2-luw, odbc

How do you use SQLBindParameter to write an array of strings to a VARCHAR field in DB2 in a memory-efficient way?

The example in the [DB2 docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/odbc/src/tpc/db2z_fnbindparameter.html) does this

```
SQLCHAR Description[NUM_PRODS][257] = {
    "Aquarium-Glass-25 litres", "Aquarium-Glass-50 litres",
    "Aquarium-Acrylic-25 litres", "Aquarium-Acrylic-50 litres",
    "Aquarium-Stand-Small", "Aquarium-Stand-Large",
    "Pump-Basic-25 litre", "Pump-Basic-50 litre",
    "Pump-Deluxe-25 litre", "Pump-Deluxe-50 litre",
    "Pump-Filter-(for Basic Pump)",
    "Pump-Filter-(for Deluxe Pump)",
    "Aquarium-Kit-Small", "Aquarium-Kit-Large",
    "Gravel-Colored", "Fish-Food-Deluxe-Bulk",
    "Plastic-Tubing"
};

rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 257, 0, Description, 257, NULL);
```

I can get that to work without issues but it isn't very efficient since each string is stored using 256 characters(+null-terminator) regardless of its actual length. More generally, if you had one very long string (say 500 chars) and every other string was one character, you would still need a two-dimensional array of size [NUM_STRINGS][500] which wastes a lot of memory.

What I would like to do is pass SQLBindParameter an array that looks like

```
SQLCHAR* Description[NUM_STRINGS];
```

where each element of the array points to a string. This would be more memory-efficient since each string only uses the space it needs but I can't figure out how to get it to work using SQLBindParameter. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: General answers for any DB would be great but answers that are specific to DB2 would also be helpful.

The sizes I am working with involve millions of strings with widely varying lengths so being memory-efficient is a significant factor.

I am actually using DB2 on Linux, but for this specific usecase, the only example I could find was in the DB2 for z/OS docs. It does work correctly though except for the memory usage issue.

Comment: Which memory utilization do you worry about? C program runtime memory or the database bufferpool and table storage space? If the latter, `VARCHAR` values are stored using their actual length, so you do not need to be concerned about that.

Comment: @mustaccio. I'm looking at the C runtime memory. As you point out, the DB itself will store it efficiently, it's when the array is in memory before calling SQLBindParameter that it takes up a lot of excess space.

Comment: "A lot" means what exactly in bytes?

Comment: As described in the question, if you have one string with 501 chars and 1000 strings with one character, you will be wasting 500,000 bytes (500 X 1000). This is because you will need to allocate 501 characters for every string regardless of it's actual size. If you have a million strings with one character, you are wasting 500 x 1000000 = ~ 500MB. And so on ...

Comment: If you insert 1 million rows at a time using SQL, you have a bigger problem on your hands. 1K or 10K rows should not be an issue, unless you're writing software for a Mars rover. You can also collect all 1-character strings in one batch and all 500-character strings in another batch.

Comment: I think we're drifting away from the original question here. I don't know why you think 1 mm rows is too much ... I am able to insert far more than 1mm rows just fine if I use the technique from the DB2 docs. The 500 chars and 1 character example I gave is just an example to illustrate the problem. As mentioned, the actual data has strings with widely varying lengths ... and maybe it is for the Mars rover :-)